# Geometric interpretation of unitary operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear map on vector space $V$ defined as $T(v) = v-2( v ,u)u$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product and $u$ a unit vector. The question is to show that $\det(T)= -1$ , $T$ is clearly an unitary operator. How to interpret this map geometrically? Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Extend $u$ to an orthonormal basis $\{u,w_1,\dots, w_{n-1}\}$. Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis. Then compute the determinant using expansion by minors.

Unitary operators are change of basis operators that respect the inner product. The picture I have in my head geometrically is some combination of a rotation and a reflection, though of course these do not exhaust the set of unitary operators.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(v,u)u$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $u$.